# /dev/graphics/fb0 is missing in emulated Android 13

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-emulator, android-source

I'm running an Android 13 emulator (x86_64, API 33). I remember it was possible to access the framebuffer directly through `/dev/graphics/fb0` or `/dev/fb0`, but it looks like in Android 13 the device is missing.

```
emulator64_x86_64:/ # ls /dev
__properties__                              full                    hvc24  hvc45  hvc9          socket
android_pipe                                fuse                    hvc25  hvc46  hw_random     stderr
ashmem                                      goldfish_address_space  hvc26  hvc47  hwbinder      stdin
ashmemb86baf7a-cf14-4987-8354-05cc05881cc7  goldfish_pipe           hvc27  hvc48  input         stdout
binder                                      goldfish_sync           hvc28  hvc49  kmsg          sys
binderfs                                    hpet                    hvc29  hvc5   kmsg_debug    tty
blkio                                       hvc0                    hvc3   hvc50  loop-control  ttyS0
block                                       hvc1                    hvc30  hvc51  memcg         tun
bluetooth0                                  hvc10                   hvc31  hvc52  net           uhid
boringssl                                   hvc11                   hvc32  hvc53  null          uinput
bus                                         hvc12                   hvc33  hvc54  pmsg0         urandom
cgroup_info                                 hvc13                   hvc34  hvc55  ppp           vga_arbiter
console                                     hvc14                   hvc35  hvc56  ptmx          vhci
cpu_dma_latency                             hvc15                   hvc36  hvc57  pts           vhost-vsock
cpuctl                                      hvc16                   hvc37  hvc58  qemu_pipe     vndbinder
cpuset                                      hvc17                   hvc38  hvc59  random        vport7p0
device-mapper                               hvc18                   hvc39  hvc6   rfkill        vport7p1
dm-user                                     hvc19                   hvc4   hvc60  rtc0          vport7p2
dma_heap                                    hvc2                    hvc40  hvc61  rtc1          vport8p1
dri                                         hvc20                   hvc41  hvc62  rtc2          vsock
event-log-tags                              hvc21                   hvc42  hvc63  rtc3          zero
fd                                          hvc22                   hvc43  hvc7   selinux
fscklogs                                    hvc23                   hvc44  hvc8   snd
```

It seems like there is no `fb` device anymore:

```
emulator64_x86_64:/ # cat /proc/devices
Character devices:
  1 mem
  4 ttyS
  5 /dev/tty
  5 /dev/console
  5 /dev/ptmx
 10 misc
 13 input
 81 video4linux
108 ppp
116 alsa
128 ptm
136 pts
166 ttyACM
180 usb
189 usb_device
216 rfcomm
226 drm
229 hvc
234 hidraw
235 rpmb
236 ttyGS
237 uio
238 bsg
239 watchdog
240 iio
241 remoteproc
242 ptp
243 pps
244 cec
245 lirc
246 media
247 rtc
248 dma_heap
249 dax
250 dimmctl
251 ndctl
252 rpmsg_char
253 pmsg
254 gpiochip
507 virtio-portsdev
508 virtio-portsdev
509 gnss
510 binder
511 roccat

Block devices:
  1 ramdisk
  7 loop
  8 sd
 65 sd
 66 sd
 67 sd
 68 sd
 69 sd
 70 sd
 71 sd
128 sd
129 sd
130 sd
131 sd
132 sd
133 sd
134 sd
135 sd
179 mmc
252 zram
253 virtblk
254 device-mapper
259 blkext
```

How can I access the framebuffer of the Android emulator?

Comment: Related: [Why is the FrameBuffer missing on some Android devices?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/232608/3573)